# Roots Sage 10: getting error: "Error occurred while trying to proxy: localhost:3000/"

Tags: roots-sage

Has anyone been able to make [Roots Sage 10](https://roots.io/sage/) work on Windows?

The following builds on [this thread](https://discourse.roots.io/t/getting-error-error-occurred-while-trying-to-proxy-localhost-3000/25505) on Sage forum.

I'm using [Local WP](https://localwp.com/) with my website accessible through `http://my-site.local/`. WSL terminal. I'm getting this error when visiting `http://localhost:3000`:

> Error occurred while trying to proxy: localhost:3000/

`Bud.config.js`:

```
app
    .setUrl('http://localhost:3000')
    .setProxyUrl('http://my-site.local/')
    .watch(['resources/views', 'app']);
```

`Package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "browserslist": [
    "extends @roots/browserslist-config"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.0.0"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "bud dev",
    "build": "bud build",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@roots/bud": "6.12.2",
    "@roots/bud-tailwindcss": "6.12.2",
    "@roots/sage": "6.12.2"
  }
}
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: Can we be confident that Sage is the issue? The error sounds like the connection isn't even making it to your Wordpress installation; in other words, something with Local WP?

Comment: I have never used this product before but using/building similar software leads me to believe you need to edit your windows hosts file. You need to add `my-site.local` in your hosts file and point it to `127.0.0.1` then your app will receive the request and be able to handle it, otherwise your computer actually tries to route to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

****1. Configure Bud****

Open the `bud.config.js` file and update the `setUrl()` and `setProxyUrl()` methods to point to your local development environment. For example, if your website is accessible through `http://my-site.local/`, you would update the `setProxyUrl()` method to `.setProxyUrl('http://my-site.local/')`.

****2. Start Bud****

```
yarn dev
```

This will start Bud and open a development server at `http://localhost:3000`. You should now be able to access your Sage 10 site at `http://localhost:3000`.

Comment: I am running into the same issue, tried everything including your suggestion above but all in vain. Can you please help?